# Matlab: How to know if a vector V belongs to a set S?

Tags: matlab, vector

How to know if a vector `V` belongs to a set `S`?

```
V=[3 7 5]

S={[1 3],[4 9 7 22 4 5],[2 66 4],[8 66 44 12 5 71],[100 45 88 7 1 5 9 73]}
```

Comment: So what must be the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cellfun`,

```
 A = cellfun( @(x) isequal(x,V), S );
```

or

```
A = cellfun(@isequal,S,repmat({V},size(S)));
```

will give,

```
A =
 0     0     0     0     0
```

and `sum(A) > 0` will give final results.

Comment: @Shai Can't blame Kamtal on this one, he just didn't know and will learn as he gets acquainted with these complicated functions. Then, I posted a solution with that `cellfun` without `repmat`. So, take it easy on him? :)

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, as you said I'm not good with `cellfun` and `bsxfun`, but I'm trying to learn!

Answer (score 2):

**Problem case #1:**  Assuming you want to find if for each cell in `S`, there is at least one element that is also present in `V`, you can use this **[`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)** based approach -

```
out = arrayfun(@(n) any(ismember(S{n},V)),1:numel(S))
```

For the given inputs, you would get -

```
>> out
out =
     1     1     0     1     1
```

Or **[`cellfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)** based approach (though I would bet my money on `arrayfun` based approach for better performance) -

```
out = cellfun(@(x) any(ismember(x,V)),S)
```

---

**Problem case #2:** If you are looking for exact match between `V` and each cell of `S`, you can again use `arrayfun` -

```
out = arrayfun(@(n) isequal(V,S{n}),1:numel(S))
```

Comment: Thank you Divakar for your Answer, I think you are referring to my previous questions :)

Comment: @bzak haha no, I think I am referring to the question here :). Seriously what must be the output for this problem, all zeros?

Comment: @bzak Think you meant **Problem case #2** as stated in the solution?

Comment: @Divakar you got the perfect winter bash hat today ;)

Comment: @Shai That movie was awesome and trippy!! Fear and loathing! :D

Comment: @Divakar: yes I needed the second case, but even the first situation is an interesting case to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go over each vector in the set and check if it's the same as the vector `V`:

```
for i=1:length(S)
    if (isequal(S{i},V))
        % V is in S
    end;
end;
```

Take notice that you address `S` with curly brackets `{}` to get the value of the cell and not the cell itself.